# Automatically add LDAP users to a local group

Tags: ldap, groups, sssd

I manage about 100 servers running Alma Linux 9.1, each with multiple users. Historically we've had a single account "admin" that everyone logs into when working on a server. I'm moving us over to individual LDAP users via SSSD but have hit a stumbling block with group membership.

Just as an example, on our ansible server the files under `/etc/ansible` belong to the admin user so that unprivileged users can work on them:

```
$ ls -lah /etc/ansible/
total 64K
drwxrwxr-x.   3 admin admin   71 Dec  7 11:11 .
drwxr-xr-x. 112 root  root  8.0K Jan 23 12:42 ..
-rw-rw-r--.   1 admin admin  614 Oct 14 11:28 ansible.cfg
-rw-rw-r--.   1 admin admin  377 Dec  7 11:11 ansible.conf
-rw-rw-r--.   1 admin admin  43K Feb 10 12:32 hosts
drwxr-xr-x.   2 admin admin    6 Oct 14 11:28 roles
```

Obviously ownership isn't going to help with multiple users needing to access the file, so we look at group membership. I can individually add users to a local group on a server but this is not scalable, and presents another step whenever new users are brought on.

I read a bit into the proposal for [group merging](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/Proposals/GroupMerging) but it seems like it's still [unimplemented](https://github.com/SSSD/sssd/issues/4663).

What I'd like is for any members of LDAP group *x* to be automatically added to local group *y* whenever they log in to any servers. Is this possible?

Comment: Don't have people logging into servers and making changes directly to shared files. Have them submit changes via a version control system that deploys them via a CI/CD pipeline. Now you have the opportunity for code review, change control, a useful change history (why did we make this change?), and you've sidestepped the whole issue of managing write access to shared files.

Comment: Alternately, if you already have LDAP groups, why not just make the files owned by an LDAP group that will be common across all the servers?

Comment: Honestly I wasn’t aware you could have files owned by ldap groups. Will look into that…